# Pure virtual function implementation through lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, abstract-class

Can I implement a pure virtual function using lambda, similar to Java interface implementations?

Comment: Maybe you can add some pseudo code as to easier understand what you want?

Comment: To have a pure virtual function you need an abstract class. Then you need derived class that implements the function. However, you can make a template class/function that generates a derived class with the given lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly. You can via some indirection though.

```
struct interface {
    virtual auto execute() -> int = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct lambda_impl : interface, private T {
    lambda_impl(T l) noexcept : T{l} {}

    auto execute() -> int override {
        return T::operator()();
    }
};
```

You can now construct a `lambda_impl` like so:

```
auto instance = lambda_impl{
    []{ return 42; }
};

instance.execute();
```

Comment: Should `auto instance = new lambda_impl` be `interface* instance = new lambda_impl`? Right now (in the isolated code) `struct interface` is obsolete. But maybe it's clear for the Java developer(?).

Comment: Please don’t show owning raw pointers, especially not when answering a Java developer. this *will* lead to memory leaks.